# Problem with 2GB Files in vuejs2 webpack project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I have a problem with large video files in a vuejs 2 project. when I do "npm run serve" I get "File Size is bigger then 2GB".

Ok, it is a bit unusual to use such large video files, but this is for a local 4K kiosk application.

I was wondering which plugin webpack webpack server? for that I understand and how I prevent it.

Comment: You should check which library is using this large video file - probably the problem is in this library/player and not in Vue/Webpack. Or maybe it's even in your old Node.js version?

Comment: I am using the basic html5 video tag. Actually I am Using a small video file, and change the video file in the build public folder. the player is not the problem, the problem seems something in the webpack server...

Comment: You can run the Vue-CLI directly with Node.js and provide the `--inspect-brk` command-line option to allow debugging from Chrome. Then Chrome will show the error in the console and should be able to traverse the stacktrace, put some breakpoints - in short, do a better troubleshooting.